# What is the Entity Type for Notes field

Tags: office-365, ms-project, project-online

I am trying to Update a Notes Field of a Task in project online.
It gives me an error

> Incompatible type kinds were found. The type 'Edm.String' was found to
>   be of kind 'Primitive' instead of the expected kind 'Entity'.

Does anyone know what is the Entity Type of Notes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is the Entity Type of Notes?**

`Task notes`  are stored as `RTF (rich text format) binary data` . So its Entity Data Model should be `Edm.Binary` rather than `Edm.String`

For more details check [Entity Data Model: Primitive Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee382832(v=vs.110).aspx)

**[Update]**

Based on this [Microsoft Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcproject.projectdataset.taskrow.task_notes(v=office.14).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) `Task notes` is a read-only field that is entered via Microsoft project and stored as `RTF (rich text format) binary data`, so you can't update it.

Comment: Still giving the same error "Incompatible type kinds were found. The type 'Edm.Binary' was found to be of kind 'Primitive' instead of the expected kind 'Entity'."

Comment: are you sure you can update this field ? I think it's a read-only field that can be entered by Microsoft project , should you check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcproject.projectdataset.taskrow.task_notes(v=office.14).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: Yes you are right..It seems that i cant update it.