# Project Server - Updating notes on a task through REST/CSOM

Tags: rest, csom, jsom, project-server

I've been racking my brain over this for a while and Googling has failed me so I was hoping I could get some help here.

I just want to be able to update the Notes field on a Project Task in Project Server through REST/CSOM. I've tried the `patch` like so and it didn't work:

```
fetch(projApiUrl + "/Draft/Tasks('" + taskId + "')", {
    method: 'PATCH',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        "__metadata": { "type": "PS.DraftTask" },
        "Notes": "UPDATED NOTES TEXT"
    }),
    headers: fetchHeaders
});
```

It returned a 204, but the value didn't change at all.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [What is the Entity Type for Notes field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/198997/what-is-the-entity-type-for-notes-field).

Comment: The [Notes field is read-only](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/ms459818(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#code-snippet-1).

Comment: @RachelHettinger Yeah, it is unfortunately, but I was hoping for perhaps a workaround to do it. It doesn't make sense to me that you can update it through the UI, but not through code.